# How to give style in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

i have a database column.(SQL column)

warning 1) Lütfen dikkatli olunuz.
warning 1) Please be careful.

warning 2) Lütfen detay yazınız
warning 2) Please write detail info.

i want to see it in Crstal Report  like that:

**warning 1) Lütfen dikkatli olunuz**.
**warning 1)** Please be careful.

**warning 2)** Lütfen detay yazınız
**warning 2)** Please write detail info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming each line is the entire record from the DB? So "warning 1) Please be careful" is the value.

I'm also assuming that every non-english phrase has a corresponding translation immediately afterwards (perhaps you have ordered it that way)

My understanding is that you want the warnings to be bolded, you want the non-english phrase to be bolded, and you want the english phrase to remain normal.

If so, you can split the string into two parts: one for the warning #, the other for the statement.

The first formula will take the first two items in the split result. Place this in the details section, right-click --> format field. Then go to font tab --> style box and choose bold.

The second formula will take the rest of the string. This will be a little trickier, because you will need to specify a condition formula for the style, but it isn't too hard. 
From your example, I will assume every odd numbered record should be bolded. So you can right-click on the formula object, format field --> font tab --> click on the X-2 next to "style" and then type in

if (recordnumber mod 2 <> 0) then 
crBold

Every other line should be bolded now.
Note that this only works if the assumptions above are satisfied.